# How to resolve NoMethodError using ROR-4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can anybody answer how to resolve the following error using ROR ?

Error:

```
NoMethodError in ImagesController#uploadFile
undefined method `[]' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x37973b8>

Extracted source (around line #0):
```

My code snippets are given below.

views/images/index.html.erb

```
<h1>File Upload</h1>
<%= form_for @image,:url => {:action => 'uploadFile'},
                    :multipart => true do |f| %>
<p><label for="upload_file">Select File</label> :
  <%= f.file_field :datafile %></p>
<%= f.submit "Upload" %>
<% end %>
```

controller/images_controller.rb

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @image=Image.new
  end
  def uploadFile
    post = Image.save(params[:image][:datafile])
    render :text => "File has been uploaded successfully"
  end
end
```

model/image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.save(upload)
    name =  upload['datafile'].original_filename
    directory = "public/data"
    # create the file path
    path = File.join(directory, name)
    # write the file
    File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(upload['datafile'].read) }
  end
end
```

migrate\20150115060041_create_images.rb

```
class CreateImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :images do |t|
      t.string :datafile

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Please help me to resolve the above error.Thanks in advance..

Comment: I can give you some pointers on how to debug this. Firstly it looks as if no file is being uploaded. Take a look at the gem `awesome-print` and within your methods print out the objects at various stages, you will see in your console what is being output

Answer (score 0):

Fist, You are calling the save method like this in controller

`post = Image.save(params[:image][:datafile])`

Then inside Image Model. U R again trying to access `[datafile]`, where as the object u passed is already the `datafile`, hence u r getting the error.

Change this in image model

```
upload['datafile']
```

To Just

```
upload
```